# htaccess rule to remove trailing slash except in one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I understand this question has been asked elsewhere on here but the solutions in those threads have not worked for me. I want to eliminate the trailing slash from my all my site's URLs with 301 redirects but I need this rule to NOT apply to my checkout page (https://example.com/checkout/onepage/), which is an Ajax thing where you advance through 3 steps of checkout process that all take place on the one URL. That URL (https://example.com/checkout/onepage/) is the only time we use https URLs on the site and I'm wondering if that's part of the issue.

The rewrite rule I have does remove my trailing slashes, but does not allow me to advance through the checkout process. Clicking the "Next" button does nothing and eventually times out.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I fix my rule?

Comment: _https URLs on the site and I'm wondering if that's part of the issue._ Do you have `AllowOverride All` for https virtual host? You typically have two vhosts one for 80 and one for 443.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

And test it after clearing browser cache.

Comment: No...checkout process still doesn't work with that rule in place.

Comment: I cannot test your checkout process. I can only test this rule and this works fine on my Apache. It is better if you edit the question and provide full .htaccess.